# How to change row/column background color in Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to use some atributes of rowdefinition, but it doesn't help me. I also tried to use `Grid.Rows[0].BackColor = Color.Red;` but it doesn't work too.

```
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Grid` does not provide a simple way to color its "cells".

There are ways to color them, and the most easiest is to simply use a `Border`:

```
<Grid>
    <!-- At the top so that they don't overlap anything else. -->
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />
    ...
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thx! And how can I change every cell using loop/cycle?

Comment: @Roomey if you need functionality of some kind of list, then its better to use `ListView` or `ListBox`, there you can set alternating colors to each row. If you need specifically `Grid` and change cells' colors, then it is most likeiy an XY problem.

Answer (score 2):

How can I change every cell using loop/cycle?
reply !!

```
 <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

you can use.

```
 foreach (Border item in gridMain.Children)
        {
            if (item.Background == Brushes.Blue)
                item.Background = Brushes.Red;
            else
                item.Background = Brushes.Blue;
        }
```

Comment: Better use `gridMain.Children.OfType<Children>()` or it may throw in case there are not just borders.